# How to create one ws-connection from one ip-address?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to create only one connection from one ip-address? If there is a connection in the first window, but the user creates a new connection in a second window, then make the change and return to the old connection. Is it possible?

```
var sessions = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var address = socket.handshake.address.address;

  if (sessions[address]) {
    // what can I do here?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented, but you can use `socket.disconnect();` to send a disconnect message to the client (graceful disconnection) or you can call `socket.disconnect(true);` to provide a forceful/abrupt disconnection.

[Reference](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L384-L401)